# Palabras del mapuzungun en el español

Tags: modismos, comparación-de-idiomas, chile

El **mapuzungun** es el idioma de la etnia **mapuche**, que es la principal base nativa del mestizaje en mi país Chile. La influencia del mapuzungun en el español es baja, en comparación con la que se dio en otras zonas latinoamericanas, pero algunas palabras se usan muchísimo y la mayoría de los chilenos se asombraría de saber que no son españolas sino mapuches.

Me gustaría saber si alguna de estas palabras, que repito son muy frecuentes en Chile, la identifica alguno de ustedes, o si se sabe de algún préstamo del mapuzungun que haya pasado al español "mundial".

> cahuín = chisme
>
> charcha = de mala calidad
>
> chape = trenza o moño en el pelo
>
> cuncuna = oruga
>
> funar = arruinar
>
> guata = abdomen
>
> laucha = ratón
>
> piñén = suciedad corporal
>
> pololo = novio, trabajo temporal
>
> quiltro = perro mestizo
>
> trapicarse = atorarse

**Edición:**

Muchas gracias a quienes compartieron sus observaciones. Esperaba un montón de buenos ejemplos y poder incluir este post en la bibliografía de un informe estupendo, pero la única conclusión posible, a fin de cuentas, es que el mapuzungún no ha tenido ninguna influencia fuera de Chile.

Comment: La única palabra que conozco es "pololo/polola" se puso de moda aquí en México hace unos años y aún la escucho de vez en cuando.

Comment: *Laucha* se usa en Argentina, y según el DRAE también en Bolivia, Paraguay y Uruguay. *Guata* alguna vez la escuché, también figura su uso en DRAE. *Pololo* la conocía pero únicamente por haberla escuchado en Chile. Las demás, nunca.

Comment: En España el uso de "pololo" es para referirse a una prenda femenina: http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pololo

Comment: Me atreveré a decir que por esto lados (Colombia), ni una.

Comment: No puedo hablar por toda la Península Ibérica, pero diría que ninguna de esas ha llegado aquí.

Comment: Tu conclusión parece ser correcta. Nunca he oído ninguna de las palabras de tu pregunta aquí en Colombia

Comment: Rodrigo: [veo](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674) que tenemos la etiqueta [chilenismo] y [chile]. ¿Te parece oportuno que las juntemos? No veo distinción posible entre ellas. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @fedorqui _Júntelas al tiro nomás socito_. O sea sí :)

Comment: @Rodrigo oh, gracias por la respuesta. Me quedo con la duda de qué es _al tiro_ (entiendo que _de inmediato_) y _socito_. Me las apunto para preguntar por ellas :)

Comment: Socito es socio + ito. Es como decir "amiguito", "camarada", aunque generalmente se usa con terceros para entrar en confianza. _Socito, ¿le limpio los vidrios?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay unos ejemplos que se han difundido (un poco) fuera de Chile:

- [*laucha*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/laucha), `Argentina, Bolivia, Paraguay, Uruguay`
- [*pucho*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/pucho), `Perú, Bolivia, Río de la Plata`
- [*pichi*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/pichi), `Río de la Plata`
- [*chuico*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/chuico), `Bolivia`
- [*natre*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/natre), `Bolivia, Perú`
- [*quilo*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/quilo), `Perú`
- [*pilcha*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/pilcha), `Cono Sur`
- [*huincha*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/huincha), [*ulpo*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/ulpo), `Argentina, Perú`
- [*malón*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/mal%C3%B3n), `Argentina, Uruguay`
- [*quinchamalí*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/quinchamal%C3%AD), `Argentina, Bolivia`
- [*coltro*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/coltro), [*mara*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/mara), `Patagonia (Argentina)`
- [*cari*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/cari), [*guachi*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/guachi) (tb. *guache, huachi*), [*Guaminí*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Guamin%C3%AD), [*güiña*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%BCi%C3%B1a) (tb. *hüiña, hüiño*), [*huilliche*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/huilliche) (*huiliche*), [*huinca*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/huinca), [*loica*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/loica) (*lloica*), [*machi*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/machi), [*maqui*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/maqui), [*mañío*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/ma%C3%B1%C3%ADo), [*ñanco*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%B1anco), [*ñiré*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%B1ir%C3%A9), [*pehuén*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/pehu%C3%A9n), [*peñi*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/pe%C3%B1i), [*quiaca*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/quiaca), [*quila*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/quila), [*tiuque*](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/tiuque) `Argentina`

Todos los demás se refieren a comidas típicas, a plantas y a animales endémicos; son apellidos; o se usan solo en Chile (o más específicamente, una gran cantidad se usan solo en isla de [*Chiloé*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archipi%C3%A9lago_de_Chilo%C3%A9)).

Así que, no parece que ningún palabra es común en el español 'mundial'.

---

- [https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Categoría:ES:Palabras_de_origen_mapuche](https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Categor%C3%ADa:ES:Palabras_de_origen_mapuche)
- [*Los mapuchismos en el DRAE*](https://scielo.conicyt.cl/scielo.php?pid=S0718-93032010000200008&script=sci_arttext), Gilberto Sánchez Cabezas

Answer (score 3):

De acuerdo a [esta referencia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_chileno#Pr.C3.A9stamos_l.C3.A9xicos_de_origen_mapuche)

> En la vigesimosegunda edición del Diccionario de la lengua española (DRAE), se cuentan 302 términos de origen mapuche que abarcan distintos campos semánticos.

La verdad es que no reconozco ninguno de los términos de tu lista (o de la de este primer enlace) como términos usados cotidianamente en España.

No sé si existe una palabra en español procedente del mapuche que se use en todos los dialectos, pero de [esta otra lista exhaustiva de palabras en español de origen mapuche](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/Categor%C3%ADa:ES:Palabras_de_origen_mapuche) reconozco (que se usen en España en el sentido que muestra la etimología mapuche):

- lapa
- mango (quizá esta sea casi completamente universal, ya que se refiere a la fruta que probablemente sea originaria de esas regiones)

Comment: @Rodrigo, conseguiste validar alguna de estas palabras? Hay alguna palabra en el Español universal proveniente del mapuzungun?

Answer (score 3):

Te puedo decir con lágrimas en los ojos que las 2 únicas palabras con que el pueblo mapuche salió al mundo son:

**poto**: culo

**pichula**: pene

Las dos son usadas en partes de Perú, Bolivia y Argentina.

*Poncho* no es mapudungun, aquí manta se dice (decía) makuñ. Poncho es quechua, de ahí vino la palabra. Los chilenos dicen poncho pero los mapuches prefieren manta, que es como se dice en el campo.

Muchas palabras mapuches vienen del quechua, porque era parte del imperio inca, pero "poto" significa otra cosa en quechua (*jarro*). En mapuche significa "trasero".

"Pichula" igual que "pinin", "pico", "pichi" es una onomatopeya de "orinar" unida a la palabra quechua "chunchula" que significa tripa. "Pinin" es pene en mapudungun. "Pico" es como los chilenos le dicen al pene en confianza. "Pichí" es orina. "Pichula" es "pene" pero más grosero.

Comment: Me parece bastante sorprendente. Habría que verificar que esas palabras realmente se usan en otros países. En [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?pichula) se sugiere que pichula proviene del árabe o del inglés "piss tool".

Answer (score 2):

De todas las palabras de la lista quizás "funar" la veo un uso más extendido. Usada como adjetivo: **funesto** es algo ruinoso, desastroso.

Comment: *Funesto* viene del latín *funestus*.

Comment: Enlace a referencia para completar la buena observación de Jaime: [Etimología de Funesto](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?funesto)

Comment: El "funar" que se usa en Chile viene del mapuzungun "podrido". Cuando los manifestantes opositores al gobierno hacen desórdenes en el Senado para evitar una ley, están "funando la ley". Ese evento se llama una "funa". "¿Vas a ir a la funa?" Si sobreescribes un documento y no lo puedes recuperar, "funaste el trabajo" o "te funaste".

Answer (score 2):

Sé que es muuuy tarde para responder, pero [las palabras poncho y coypu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_from_indigenous_languages_of_the_Americas#Words_from_other_indigenous_languages_of_the_Americas) (coypo) son reconocidas como usadas en inglés. Lamentablemente, *punchu* también exisitía en Quechua y su origen es discutible.

Una fuente fértil de estas palabras son las especies nativas, algunas (pocas) de las cuales han alcanzado fama afuera, como la araucaria (de la que la *Araucaria araucana* es tipo), el huemul y el choro/chorito.

**Edición:** Quizá un poco más lejos de lo que buscas, pero todavía en el campo de palabras de origen mapudungún y ámbito universal, están los nombres y topónimos del [sistema solar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Cato_censor): Colocolo, Caupolicán, Lautaro y Galvarino son asteroides; Lebu, Lota y Rengo son cráteres en Marte, y por último, Pillán ocupa parte importante de la superficie de Io, una de las lunas principales de Júpiter.

**Edición 2:** el [pudú](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pud%C3%BA), el ciervo más pequeño del mundo y nativo del sur de Chile y parte de Argentina, tiene nombre de origen mapudungún, y recibe ese nombre no sólo en castellano universal, sino en [muchos otros idiomas](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q848656#sitelinks-wikipedia).

Comment: Uno podría argumentar que el poncho llegó de los migrantes chilenos a California durante la [fiebre del oro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_rush#North_America), pero demostrarlo requeriría una investigación profunda

Comment: The animal is coypu in English, not coypo. We do use poncho too. According to Wikepedia araucaria is derived from de Arauco and is not called that by the Mapuche https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Araucaria (The Spanish wikpedia does not have the Mapuche word but the English does).

Comment: You are right, they call it *pewén*, I missed that! Nevertheless, the word Arauco is a Spanish name given to a Mapuche-inhabited region. It's been argued that the name itself may come from Quechua or Mapudungún. I find the second one far more plausible since Quechua-speaking people never reached Arauco (and the roots offered for both languages are rather distant).